# Configure a custom layout for nuget repository in artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory

My organization is new to artifactory and currently uses it in a pretty rudimentary way: dumping all of our many nuget packages and their versions into the pre-fab `snapshot` local repository. This repository has the `nuget-default` layout associated with it, which has the following artifact path pattern it's trying to match on/parse metadata about packages:

```
[orgPath]/[module]/[module].[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).nupkg
```

This is obviously not working as we haven't configured our CI to push packages to nested subfolders/we use a different versioning pattern in our filename, etc. This is problematic as we don't get to take advantage of any of the artifact management features like automatic cleanup of old versions, etc.

I'm attempting to setup a "Custom Layout" to fix this, but cannot get it to match/parse any meta data. Configuration details:

```
// CI configuration
// Build and push packages to
https://myOrg.jfrog.io/myOrg/api/nuget/snapshot-new/myOrg/radModule
// instead of
https://myOrg.jfrog.io/myOrg/api/nuget/snapshot


// cool-custom-layout settings
Artifact Path Pattern: [orgPath]/[module]/[module].[baseRev]-[fileItegRev].nupkg
Folder Integration Revision RegExp: .*
File Integration Revision RegExp: .*
```

When I push a package to this newly configured `snapshot-new` repository named `RadModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`, it shows up in the repository with the correctly nested folder structure/file path (`snapshot-new/myOrg/radModule/RadModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`).

**The Problem** When I attempt to use the `Test Artifact Path Resolution` form in the `cool-custom-layout` edit view, it fails to match/parse any data out. I've tried submitting the following test values and they all fail:

- `myOrg/radModule/RadModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`
- `snapshot-new/myOrg/radModule/RadModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`
- `RadModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this issue out, thought I would answer in case anyone else has similar woes. Pretty simple error: since the `[module]` variable is referenced twice in my sample artifact path pattern, it seems to require that the literals have the *exact same value*. In my example, the first value is `radModule` (camelCased) while the second value is `RadModule` (PascalCased). As such, the following amended test value parses correctly:

`myOrg/radModule/radModule.2017.20.4-gitabc123.nupkg`